# Translate Excel if condition from Excel to Python

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-3.9

I'm trying to translate a If statement from excel to python.

I know that for excel, If statement we have:

`IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`

For IFERROR statement we have:

`IFERROR(value, value_if_error)`

OR function:

`The OR function returns TRUE if any of its arguments evaluate to TRUE, and returns FALSE if all of its arguments evaluate to FALSE.`

For Python I want to replicate the below two excel if statement.

`=IF( OR(IFERROR(AM2+0=0, AM2=""), DK2<>" "), " ", AM2)`

Here AM2,DK2 are columns in excel file and <> represents not equal in excel.

Can anyone help me translate this into Python it was quiet confusing for me.

Comment: Can you please add some examples?
Because the answer depends on what data types do you have. Especially in the case of `AM2+0=0`. What does it mean? Is there text `'0'` or what?

Comment: Hi Both AM2 and DK2 are numeric columns but some values contain both blank  value and spaces so to confirm adding 0 to it.

Comment: Look at `numpy.where`, import numpy as np.     np.where(<condition>, df['col1'], df['col2'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (if we talk about pandas DataFrame):

```py
df['whatever'] = np.where(
    (df['AM'] == 0) | (df['AM'].isna()) | (df['AM'] == " ") | (df['DK'] != ' ') | (df['AM'] == ""),
    "ZZZ",
    df['AM']
)
```

I used letters as column names since no column names were provided.